# jar image from jlink does not show org.kordamp.materialdesign2 icons but they load when program is run in intellij

Tags: java, javafx, javafxports, javafx-webengine

## javafx applications not showing org.kordamp.materialdesign2 icons

I recently completed a school management program with JavaFX 18 which runs properly using the normal IntelliJ run configurations but fails to load ALL icons from org.kordamp.materialdesign2. I have scanned the entire web and come across a few answers regarding service files. I have all three required packages in my module-info file **org.kormap.ikoli.core,org.kordamp.javafx and org.kordamp.materialdesign2**

When the jar is run, it shows messages like this:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'mdi2o-office-building'
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.AbstractIkonResolver.resolve(AbstractIkonResolver.java:61)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.IkonResolver.resolve(IkonResolver.java:73)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.lambda$new$2(FontIcon.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:106)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:82)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.setIconCode(FontIcon.java:231)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.<init>(FontIcon.java:97)
    at manager.school_manager.EntryController.initialize(EntryController.java:115)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at manager.school_manager.Entry.start(Entry.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

[**error messages on running jar**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tGzU.png) |
[**Program without icons on running jar**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHWIU.png) |
[**Program showing icons when run in intellij**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G5AF.png)

[module-info.java with all three co-dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT7v7.png)

## **Tried using the shadow jar plugin as stated in it's documentation**

[**build.gradle file showing use of shadow jar plugin**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxAaq.png)

Also opened the jar file with winrar and checked the Manifest/Manifest.MF/services and here is what I found:

[it shows two files related to ikonli. Am not quite versed to services in general so I can't tell if these would suffice.*** I would gladly accept any help that would help me resolve this problem***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Wi9.png)

Comment: How are those icons addressed in your *code*, e.g. *mdi2o-office-building*?

Comment: [Also](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/) *Here’s for example the minimum settings required for a JavaFX application
module-info.java ...requires org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome;*

Comment: @g00se,thanks for responding. heres a sample of the icon presentation in my code

Comment: @g00se  `        FontIcon projectIcon =  new FontIcon(MaterialDesignO.OFFICE_BUILDING);
        projectIcon.setIconSize(12);
        projectLabel.setGraphic(projectIcon);`

Comment: `       ** FontIcon projectIcon =  new FontIcon(MaterialDesignO.OFFICE_BUILDING);**
        projectIcon.setIconSize(12);
        projectLabel.setGraphic(projectIcon);`

Comment: so brief, I use the materialdesign2 enums eg MaterialDesign2A.ACOUNT_CIRCLE

Comment: You've built an executable *fat* jar? If not, it won't find that kordamp dependency

Comment: @g00se. Its built using  intellij artifacts. Am not sure if thats a fat jar. sorry am originally from a python background. Please tell me, how i make it fat :)

Comment: I can't say as I don't use IntelliJ. Are you using Maven under the covers?

Comment: @g00se Yes i am.

Comment: Have maven [copy the dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) (jar files) to your output directory (not shading them all together).  You will have multiple jar files.  When you run the app, use the `-p` option to place the directory with the jar files on the module path.  Ensure that you define proper module-info for your app as documented for JavaFX and your required dependencies.  Alternately, use jlink via the JavaFX maven plugin if your app has no automatic modules or perhaps jpackage otherwise.

Comment: What I described is for desktop apps. You mention [javafxports](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports) for embedded apps.  I know nothing about that.  You should contact Gluon directly for assistance with that.

Comment: When it comes to distribution, you will want either a fat jar or (sounder) a `jpackage`d solution. So @jewelsea is probably right to recommend `jlink` over a fat jar approach as it's a step on the road to `jpackage`. JavaFX is relatively problematic to jar as the runtime is non-standard

Comment: I removed the JavaFX 11 tag as you state you are using JavaFX 18.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jewelsea I am using jlink. Its automatically configured into the project when created using intellij javafx plugin. EVERY item in the resource dir, [images,fonts etc] load properly so it must be an improperly configured dependency issue.  i have all three codependencies ikonli.javafx,ikonli.core and the icon package ikonli.materialdesign2.    All works well when run from intellij but the jar shows no ikonli icons except the images from the resource directory.  the icons are included in the project as such         DemoLabel.setGraphic(new FontIcon(MaterialDesignA.Account_Circle));

Comment: @jewelsea   i read a few solutions regarding service files, so i opened the bundled jar with winrar and noticed that in the Manifest-Mf dir,  Ikonli.IkonProvider and Ikonli.IkonHandler where included.I am told three service files are needed. dono what am missing.been on this for three days.the project all complete except for the icons which completely destroys the look and feel. I need help. willing to upload the entire project to gdrive if necessary.its nothing secure.Just a school management system to generate reports.

Comment: Your question talks about an "executable jar" in the title and in the body it talks about a "shadow jar".  `jlink` does not create an executable jar, it creates a runtime image.  It doesn't matter if the maven jlink plugin is in your project, if you are not using it by calling [`mvn javafx:jlink`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options).  I don't know if it is something you want to use or not as it is different than your state goal of an executable jar.

Comment: @jewelsea true.very true. i suppose i did comfound the two. a runtime image it is then. am not quite use to java terminology.i just know enough to build basic utilities.but yes i do run the jar from command line. How does this help. please

Comment: @jewelsea here the jlink script in the build.gradle file              jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip") as RegularFile
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

Comment: Well, it is a different question with a different solution.  An executable jar requires different tools and packaging to build and to use it you need a pre-installed java runtime.  With bundling of the correct components, the jar can be made to be cross-platform across different systems.  A jlink image can be distributed as a zip file that is extracted and a shell script that runs the app (or packaged in an installer via jpackage), it does not require a java runtime installed on the system and is not cross-platform, it will only run on the given target platform.

Comment: I don't use gradle much, I use maven, I cannot help you with questions related to a gradle build.

Comment: By default, jlink does not link service implementations.  I don't know if that is your issue or not.  You could try with the [`--bind-services`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) option and see if it makes a difference.  Binding all services will result in a large linked image, but that may not matter.  If it does fix your issue, you can either just keep the large image or bind the individual service implementations required via the `--add-modules` switch.  Also, if you use jlink, make sure you don't use `shadowJar { mergeServiceFiles() }`.

Comment: Your suggestion of uploading is probably a good idea

Comment: @MarvinNewton Please don't screenshot text, instead place it in the question as text formatted as code - it is much easier to work with that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Example app**

- Uses jlink to link the app into an image that is zipped for deployment, rather than packaging the app as an executable jar (because this is what the asker stated they wanted to do in comments).
- Uses maven for build and packaging, as that is what I am familiar with.
- Will create an app usable only on the same platform type and architecture as the machine used to build the app.

Build requires Maven installation and JDK 20 installation.  Deployment is standalone and has no dependencies other than the OS it runs on.

`src/main/java/module-info.java`

```
module com.example.materialicons {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2;

    exports com.example.materialicons;
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>materialicons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>materialicons</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-materialdesign2-pack</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.materialicons/com.example.materialicons.IconApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>iconapp</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>iconapp</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>iconapp</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`src/main/java/com/example/materialicons/IconApplication.java`

Material Design has icon packs, named A -> Z.  We just use the A icon pack here, usage of icons from other packs is similar.

```
package com.example.materialicons;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2.MaterialDesignA;

public class IconApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FlowPane layout = new FlowPane();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setPrefWrapLength(500);
        for (MaterialDesignA iconEnumVal : MaterialDesignA.values()) {
            FontIcon icon = new FontIcon(
                    iconEnumVal.getDescription()
            );
            icon.setIconSize(40);
            layout.getChildren().add(
                    icon
            );
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(layout), 530, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Build**

Build command (execute from the project root directory):

```
mvn clean javafx:jlink
```

Build output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.example:materialicons >----------------------
[INFO] Building materialicons 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ materialicons ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/username/dev/materialicons/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:jlink (default-cli) > process-classes @ materialicons >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ materialicons ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/username/dev/materialicons/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ materialicons ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files with javac [debug target 20 module-path] to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:jlink (default-cli) < process-classes @ materialicons <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:jlink (default-cli) @ materialicons ---
[INFO] Building zip: /Users/username/dev/materialicons/target/iconapp.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

---

**Example usage**

Execute from your project root directory.  Adjust the command syntax for your OS type.

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
unzip ../target/iconapp.zip 
bin/iconapp
```

---

**Example output**

[image: icons]

Comment: my setup is identical to yours only i use gradle not maven. I am upload the completed project to gdrive as we speak. Please give me a few minuites . would drop the link in a bit. Again its nothing serious , just a school project.  Never got hooked on a single issue for more than three days. This is my last resort i guess then i may just bundle it without icons

Comment: On second thoughts,the whole project is quite builky, will upload the build.gradle,module-info

Comment: @MarvinNewton you don't need to upload your entire project to an external resource. I wouldn't look at it in any case, others may. If desired (and needed), you can provide a [mcve] with all resources inline in the question, either in this question or as a new question. I won't answer a question regarding gradle use, as I don't use it much, but others may. If you ask a new question, be clear about what you actually want (whether that be a single cross-platform jar, a zipped jlink image, or a jpackage created installer), what the target platforms are, and what the build tool is.

Answer (score 0):

**module-info.java**

```
module manager.school_manager {
    //javafx and related deps
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.jfxtras.styles.jmetro;

    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;

    requires javafx.base;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires javafx.media;

    // json io
    requires com.google.code.gson;




    //itext 7 ===> pdf deps
    requires itextpdf.layout;
    requires itextpdf.kernel;
    requires itextpdf.io;
    requires itextpdf.commons;
    requires itextpdf.pdfa;
    requires itextpdf.barcodes;

    // postgres deps
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.postgresql;

    //excel deps
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;

    //logging deps and transitive deps
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires commons.math3;


    opens manager.school_manager to javafx.fxml;
    opens manager.school_manager.controllers to javafx.fxml;

    exports manager.school_manager;
}`
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
    id 'org.gradlex.extra-java-module-info' version '1.3'
    id 'java-library'
//    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.1.0'
}


//shadowJar {
//    mergeServiceFiles()
//}
//


group 'manager'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

ext.moduleName= 'manager.school_manager'


extraJavaModuleInfo{
    failOnMissingModuleInfo.set(false)

    module("org.tinylog:tinylog-api","org.tinylog.api"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }
    module("org.tinylog:tinylog-impl","org.tinylog.impl"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }

    module("com.google.code.gson:gson","com.google.code.gson"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }
    module("io.github.typhon0:AnimateFX","io.github.typhon0"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }
    module("com.github.Dansoftowner:PDFViewerFX","com.github.Dansoftowner"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }
    module("org.apache.commons:commons-math3","commons.math3"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }
    module("com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet","SparseBitSet"){
        exportAllPackages()
        requireAllDefinedDependencies
    }



    automaticModule("fxribbon.jar","com.pixelduke.fxribbon")
    automaticModule("postgresql.jar","org.postgresql")

    automaticModule("log4j.jar","org.log4j")
    automaticModule("log4j-api.jar","org.log4j-api")
    automaticModule("slf4j-api.jar","org.slf4j")

    automaticModule("layout.jar","itextpdf.layout")
    automaticModule("kernel.jar","itextpdf.kernel")
    automaticModule("pdfa.jar","itextpdf.pdfa")
    automaticModule("io.jar","itextpdf.io")
    automaticModule("commons.jar","itextpdf.commons")
    automaticModule("barcodes.jar","itextpdf.barcodes")
    automaticModule("sign.jar","itextpdf.sign")
    automaticModule("svg.jar","itextpdf.svg")


    automaticModule("javafxweb.jar","javafx.web")
    automaticModule("javafxmedia.jar","javafx.media")


}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'manager.school_manager'
    mainClass = 'manager.school_manager.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = '11.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}


dependencies {
//    converts non modular jars to jpms compatible
    implementation('org.gradlex:extra-java-module-info:1.3')
//
//    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1')

    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.6.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('net.synedra:validatorfx:0.4.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }


    implementation('org.jfxtras:jmetro:11.6.16')
    implementation(fileTree(dir:'/libs',includes:['*.jar']))
//    implementation('org.openpnp:opencv:3.4.2-0')
//    implementation('eu.hansolo.fx:charts:17.1.27')

    implementation('org.tinylog:tinylog-api:2.6.1')
    implementation('org.tinylog:tinylog-impl:2.6.1')
    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1')
    implementation('io.github.typhon0:AnimateFX:1.2.4')

    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-materialdesign2-pack:12.3.1')
    implementation 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-core:12.3.1'
    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')


    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'){
        exclude(group: "javax.xml")
    }
    implementation('com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2')

    implementation 'org.kordamp.jipsy:jipsy-annotations:1.2.0'
//    implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.13'


    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip") as RegularFile
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

**Main.java**  *** a simple entry that show the icon implementation throughout the code in a simple Label ***

```
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2.*;
... other imports  






public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        System.out.println("LAUCHING SMPRO....");

//      loading main.fxml
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL fxmlLocation = ResourceAnchor.getAppResource("views/main.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(fxmlLocation);
        loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(StaticNames.RESOURCE_BUNDLE_BASENAME.getName()));
        Parent root = loader.<VBox>load();
        root.getStyleClass().add(JMetroStyleClass.BACKGROUND);

//        get controller instance
        EntryController entryController  = loader.getController();
        entryController.EntryStage.set(stage);


        Scene scene = new Scene(new Button("Click me",new FontIcon(MaterialDesignA.ACCOUNT_CIRCLE)));



        stage.setTitle("Sample title");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(ResourceAnchor.getResourceStream("images/logo.png")));

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }




}
```

Comment: Afraid to say that putting up partial code is really pointless. Also posting it as an *answer* is very misleading

Comment: An noted in one of my prior comments: "Alternately, use jlink via the JavaFX maven plugin if your app has no automatic modules or perhaps jpackage otherwise."  You have many dependencies defined as automatic modules, which won't work with jlink, because it doesn't support them.  You also, strangely, define some modules which aren't automatic modules (like JavaFX modules) as automatic modules.  You can't use jlink to create an image of your entire application.

Comment: There is some kind of workaround in the [badass-jlink-plugin](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) that you use that allows it to work with automatic modules -> "The badass-jlink plugin takes a more pragmatic approach by combining all non-modular dependencies into a single jar. This way, only the resulting merged module needs a module descriptor."  But such a workaround wouldn't be guaranteed to work with all modular software, as some software may be built to only operate as a module (should work in most cases though).

Comment: Providing assistance with the packaging and deployment of a project with so many dependencies is beyond the scope of what is feasible for StackOverflow IMO.

Comment: In your question you say you are using Java 18, but in the gradle file, it actually uses `11.0.2`, which is quite old.

Comment: Icons finally appear after attempting to use the SVGLoader from  implementation('com.github.hervegirod:fxsvgimage:1.1') to load resource svgs in place of Ikonli Icons.Dont know how that solved the issue but it did

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue here and I just think of creating my own Icon library at this point